# Terraform workspace specific lines of code in Azure

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-workspace

I'm having an issue using terraform workspaces between a region pair. One workspace for South Central US and one for North Central US. Everything works great until it comes to zones. Public IP for example. South I’m setting zones, North won’t accept zone configuration empty, 0, or 1,2, or 3 because it doesn’t support zones yet. Hoping to set zones in SCU and eventually doing the same in NCU when they become available.

How do I use the same code in both regions? I know I can use workspace vars for values, but in this case it is an entire line of code. Seems like there should be an easy answer I’m just not thinking of.

Public IP code as an example below, but it the solution I would apply for VM deployments as well.

```
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "example" {
  name                = "acceptanceTestPublicIp1"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  allocation_method   = "Static"
  zones               = [1]

  tags = {
    environment = "Production"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `terraform.workspace` variable, and set the value to `null` if you don't want to set it to anything in a specific workspace:

```
zones    = terraform.workspace == "south" ? [1] : null
```

Change `"south"` to whatever the name of your Terraform workspace is that needs to set the `zones` value.

Comment: Thanks Mark, does that just leave the zones value null or omit the whole line?  There seems to be no value I can put in "zones = " and run it in North.  zones = 0, zones = [blank],  zones = *, nothing works.   I need TF to just omit the whole line when in North.  Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Leaving it null and omitting the whole line is the same thing in Terraform.

Answer (score 0):

@Mark B, you're brilliant!  Such a simple answer that works.  Bravo!

Here's an example of my variables.tfvars

```
firewalla-AvailabilityZone    = {
    hub-ncu        = null
    hub-scu        = [1]
}
firewallb-AvailabilityZone    = {
    hub-ncu        = null
    hub-scu        = [3]
}
```

Then in the resource:

zones = var.firewalla-AvailabilityZone[terraform.workspace]

Comment: Welcome Steve to StackOverflow. Please do not post "thank you" messages as answers, use the comment section for the actual answer instead. There, a snippet about how you applied the answer is very welcome. Also, this way its author will be notified.